# Compile time error while using unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I got below sample code

```
// unordered_map::find
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main ()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string,double> mymap = {
     {"mom",5.4},
     {"dad",6.1},
     {"bro",5.9} };

  std::string input;
  std::cout << "who? ";
  getline (std::cin,input);

  std::unordered_map<std::string,double>::const_iterator got = mymap.find (input);

  if ( got == mymap.end() )
    std::cout << "not found";
  else
    std::cout << got->first << " is " << got->second;

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
```

When i try to compile it with VS 2010 on Windows 7 i get compile time error (though it look ok to me)

```
1>\testing.cpp(13): error C2552: 'mymap' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list
1>          'std::tr1::unordered_map<_Kty,_Ty>' : Types with a base are not aggregate
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=double
1>          ]
1>\testing.cpp(14): error C2078: too many initializers
1>\testing.cpp(15): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your compiler (VC10) does not support uniform initialization. Your program [compiles fine on a conforming compiler](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3SRz1U%2458).

Comment: Note that as of now, no version of VC has the library initializer list constructors yet.